# Use FileSystemWatcher in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, filesystemwatcher

I have created File system watcher for console application. it is working flawless.

unliess you press 'q' its keep listning the folder for adding files and display name of the files when found.

```
public void FileWatcher()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = @"C:\\WATCH-FOLDER";
                watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

                watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                NotifyFilters.FileName |
                NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                NotifyFilters.Security |
                NotifyFilters.Size;

                watcher.Filter = "*.*";

                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }

        }

        public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, with path {1} has been {2}", e.Name, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
        }

        public void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(" {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }
```

but now how can i use this in my web application. what i want, when ever file adds in folder it picked and and insert info in database. so when i press show all so this info would be part of existing data in table.

But i have no idea where to put function. Some people says put it in Global.asax file, and some says put in main page, or add thread. I am completly confused and have no idea how to do that.

Comment: That generally is not a good idea, since you don't have real-time communication with the client.

Comment: There is one more thing. You should remember that application pool runs only when there are clients. if noone access your web application in 20 minutes, then IIS will stop application pool, and your FileWatcher also will be stopped

Comment: What you need is to develop a process that runs independent of IIS, and monitors the folder - like the one you already developed. A monitor has no place in a web application, which, as was commented above, only runs when a client accesses it actively.

Comment: Me and @Aheho,  asked many questions down, and we expect clarification from it side!

Comment: @Admin, Do we have any rules and regulation while giving –ve marking. 
I started learning ASP.NET in last two weeks and I want to ask this important question. This question shows my effort and research which I have done in only 2 weeks. But still I got negative marking from some one, why, I really don’t have any words for that.
Do we have any criteria where Admin can give –ve marking for those who gives –ve marking to the beginners with careless attitude and try to demoralize them for asking important questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you host this file watcher in app_start in global.asap, so even if iis shut down your app after 20min of inactivity, then it will relaunch a new watcher whenever a user hit your application again.

This is a valid solution, and can be the only solution for those who don't own the server, i. e. Who host their web on shared hosting and have no access to Windows services

Comment: What if a file arrives during the time the asp.net application is shut down?

Comment: How come a user will upload a file to your website while website is shutdown?? I assume that the developer here is trying to watch the activity of his website(web app), not monitoring the whole server activities!!  The question was not clear weather he owns the server and can access all its utilities and services or he has only shared web hosting. Where the user has an access to his web app only!!!

Comment: If the file is being posted via the asp.net application, then why use a file watcher at all? Just put the processing code within the same code that is accepting the file post.

Comment: Now you are suggesting a brilliant solution: ), it's now the turn of the question initiator to clarify his web app settings and to clarify the reason why to monitor a folder content and how is this folder updated!! I think you agree with me that the question is a bit vague, right?

Comment: I agree. It would be nice to know the use case.

Answer (score 3):

This process should be placed in a windows service application. You should not attempt to host it within an asp.net application.

If you are using visual studio, then you have the ability to make Windows Services. File -> New - Project -> C# -> Window Service. The code that you have in your test console app would go in the OnStart event of a class derived from ServiceBase.

Comment: Guys, i have no idea what is windows service application. Any idea, any example. I am completly blank in ASP Web stuff

Comment: it's not ASP.Net stuff. It's usual windows service that runs in background - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service . You can write your own that will be executed while Windows executes

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late but putting aside what's right and wrong from an architectural ethics point of view this solves the problem ...

Scott Hanselman had this to say:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

... he offers up his own ideas and also refers to this ...

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

... the article talks about using this ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject.aspx

... to basically have something that behaves like a task manager / windows process embedded within the IIs worker process, which allows us to do something like this in the app ...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using WebBackgrounder;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
  typeof(SampleAspNetTimer), "Start")]

public static class SampleAspNetTimer
{
    private static readonly Timer _timer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed);
    private static readonly JobHost _jobHost = new JobHost();

    public static void Start()
    {
        _timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    }

    private static void OnTimerElapsed(object sender)
    {
        _jobHost.DoWork(() => { /* What is it that you do around here */ });
    }
}
```